# Does the database size change after migrating?

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, migration, upgrade

I've migrated a content database from SP2010 to SP2013, all went well.
However, the backup from SP2010 is 4.5GB, while when I take a backup from SP2013 it is just 3.5GB?

I'm aware of the shredded storage feature in SP2013, but as far as I know this will not be applied retrospectively when upgrading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Couple of things can change the database size.

- If There is any unused or white space inside the content database then during the backup and restore method database automatically shrink it.
- If there is any orphan items inside the content db then during db restore method it may clear those.
- There are possibility that you deleted data in SharePoint 2013 or may be there is any data inside receyle bin which automatically cleared after its retention period.
- You can check the size of site collection from central admin.